# how to run this API Server code

Tags: node.js, api

I'm new to the node Js world, and currently learning the basics, I've this code which i found online, and I want to run it and see the result, but i wasn't able to run it, can you please help me ? 
the code essentially get the Parsetime and unixtime, but I don't know what argument to pass, I tried `node api.js 3000`  and I tried `node api.js '/api/unixtime` still didn't work,

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var port = process.argv[2];

function parseTime (time) {
  return {
    hour: time.getHours(),
    minute: time.getMinutes(),
    second: time.getSeconds()
  };}

function unixTime (time) {
  return {unixtime: time.getTime()};
} 
function parseQuery (url) {
  switch (url.pathname) {
    case '/api/parsetime':
      return parseTime(new Date(url.query.iso))
    case '/api/unixtime':
      return unixTime(new Date(url.query.iso))
    default: return 'please enter a valid endpoint url'
  }}

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  // Request handeling logic.
  if (request.method === 'GET') {

    // write request status and content type to resposne head
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    var urlobj = url.parse(request.url, true);
    response.end(JSON.stringify(parseQuery(urlobj)));

  } else {
    response.writeHead(405);
    response.end();
  } });

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:%s', port)
})
```

Comment: Normally `node api.js` is enough to run the server. What is the output when you run the command? Could you please post the error you have?

Comment: it shows this 
"Server listening on http://localhost:undefined " 

and freeze on the same thing, not showing any result

Comment: Since port is taken from `process.argv[2]` then this `node api.js 3000` is correct. Do you get any error?

Comment: After running the command open your browser with this address http://localhost:3000/ and you should see the result

Comment: oh, it says " "please enter a valid endpoint url"

Comment: should I add the url after the port

Comment: oh i see the url should be on the browser tap, thank you so much man, I got it working now

Comment: Since you are now to JS and you wanna create an API I suggest you check [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/). Here are some great examples [ExpressJS Example](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples) You can start with [Hello World](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/hello-world/index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just made few changes in your script and it works !! Below is script
/***********************************/

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000
var url = require('url');
const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.url)
  response.end('Hello Node.js Server!')
}

function parseTime (time) {
    return {
      hour: time.getHours(),
      minute: time.getMinutes(),
      second: time.getSeconds()
    };}

  function unixTime (time) {
    return {unixtime: time.getTime()};
  } 
  function parseQuery (url) {
    switch (url.pathname) {
      case '/api/parsetime':
                console.log(new Date());
        return parseTime(new Date())
      case '/api/unixtime':
        return unixTime(new Date())
      default: return 'please enter a valid endpoint url'
    }}

  var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // Request handeling logic.
    if (request.method === 'GET') {

      // write request status and content type to resposne head
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

      var urlobj = url.parse(request.url, true);
      response.end(JSON.stringify(parseQuery(urlobj)));

    } else {
      response.writeHead(405);
      response.end();
    } });

  server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:%s', port)
  })
```

/***********************************/

Steps 1: In command line run : node api.js

Step 2 : Go in browser and hit http://localhost:3000/api/unixtime OR http://localhost:3000/api/parsetime